# Audio Transition Between Two Slides Using Reveal.js

Tags: javascript, audio, reveal.js

I am using reveal.js for a presentation, in one slide there is an audio file being autoplayed. I want the audio to fade out when entering the next slide, what I can think of now is set the audio file outside of any sections and set up a event listener on `slidechanged`. When, say the 1st slide is the one which the audio is on, 1st slide is on the audio should autoplay, once it's not 1st slide, the audio should fade out.

I am wondering is there any easier way to set up the transition within a section. Here is what I have for now, trying to fade out the audio on every `slidechanged` event without considering the situation when it goes back to the 1st slide. The js code below is copied from another post.

```
<section>
    <audio data-autoplay loop id="sound"><source src="assets/audio.mp3"></audio>
</section>
<script>
    Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
            // event.previousSlide, event.currentSlide, event.indexh, event.indexv
            var sound = document.getElementById("#sound");
            var fadePoint = sound.duration - 2;
            var fadeAudio = setInterval(function(){
                // Only fade if past the fade out point or not at zero already
                if ((sound.currentTime >= fadePoint) && (sound.volume != 0.0)) {
                    sound.volume -= 0.1;
                }
                // When volume at zero stop all the intervalling
                if (sound.volume === 0.0) {
                    clearInterval(fadeAudio);
                }
            },200);
</script>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?